# ransack match all associations

Tags: ruby-on-rails, search, activerecord, ransack

I have `User` model, `has_many` skills. I need to get users match all the selected skills. For example:

```
User A: Ruby, HTML, JavaScript. 
User B: Ruby
User C: Ruby, C++
```

When I search using the list of skills names or ids. I need get users have all values in this list. So, Search using `Ruby & Javascript`, I need to get `User A`.

The Problem if I used [ransack gem](https://github.com/activerecord-hackery/ransack) `skills_id_in`, It'll return all users have `Ruby` Skill. The Query is as the following:

```
SELECT \"users\".* FROM \"users\" LEFT OUTER JOIN \"user_skills\" ON \"user_skills\".\"user_id\" = \"users\".\"id\" LEFT OUTER JOIN \"skills\" ON \"skills\".\"id\" = \"user_skills\".\"skill_id\" WHERE \"skills\".\"id\" IN (1, 3)
```

If it's not allowed in ransack. Can you help **How make it in ActiveRecord & run in DB level**?

**My Opinion:** It's can't implement using [ransack params](https://github.com/activerecord-hackery/ransack/wiki/basic-searching), If you know Native Query to match all association, let me know?

Answer (score 0):

I can't seem to find a way to query a CONTAINS directly through Postgres, but the following would work:

```
result = User.joins(:skills)

skills_names = ['Ruby', 'JavaScript']
skills_names.each do |skill_name|
  result = result.where('? = ANY(name)', skill_name)
end
```

If you know how many skills you're going to be querying ahead of time, you could combine them all into one query:

```
User.joins(:skills).where('? = ANY(name) AND ? = ANY(name)', 'Ruby', 'JavaScript')
```